# ARCore: Differentiate between two planes detected in adjacent vertical walls in the room

Tags: rotation, augmented-reality, arcore, quaternions, plane

I'm working on Vertical plane detection.

When I'm pointing at wall 1 of my room, plane1 here is the vertical plane detected in wall 1...
I'm recording the quaternion via this formula

```
 val quat =  Quaternion(plane1.centerPose.qx(), plane1.centerPose.qy(), plane1.centerPose.qz(), plane1.centerPose.qw())
```

Now, when I point my phone to the other wall (adjacent) of my room and check its rotation, I get the same values, I assumed this is the world rotation. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Is there any other way where I could differentiate between vertical planes detected in adjacent walls

I'm using this to loop through the detected planes

```
 for (plane1 in frame.getUpdatedTrackables(Plane::class.java)) {
                if (plane1.trackingState === TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    val type: Plane.Type = plane1.type
                    if (type == Plane.Type.VERTICAL) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. You want to verify whether the detected vertical plane along wall A is different than that on wall B? I don't think that is possible with ARCore. Maybe you can give some more details about what you are trying to do in your app?